# Storing facebook account and email account in db

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have followed this tutorial: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-get-started-custom-authentication/ in order for me to get a user to register with his email. I have also allowed users to login with their facebook account. The people who registers through email gets put into a table which looks like:

[image]

The problem is that if I create another table which is called "Post", how will i be able to store the userId of a person authenticated through facebook? Will I have to add them to the Account table as well if they are not found when logging in through facebook? If so, how will my table be structured to account for that?

Comment: Are you asking for opinions on how to design your table relationships? This seems like an opinion question (and if not, then it's an unclear question). And don't you already have an Id in the table above that you can use? Not sure what you're looking for.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I'm asking how will I be able to add a entry into my account table when they login through facebook for the first time rather than registering? I need to do this to keep track of their settings etc. Similar to how the User.Identity works in the newest ASP's